# Subprocess Popen reassigning output

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to execute shell cmds with Popen in Python 2.7.  I can get the stdout and print it, but only once.  When I try to print it again or reassign the output variable to another, it is blank.  Here is my code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p = Popen(['cd /home/pi/GDRIVE; drive push -quiet -ignore-conflict PiDocs'],shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
output = p.communicate()[0]
print output
if p.returncode != 0:
  print p.returncode
  print "Return code was not equal to 0"
  print output
  print "now reassigning output"
  mailtext = output
  print "print output again"
  print output
  print "mailtext is next"
  print mailtext
else:
  print p.returncode
  print "Return code was equal to 0"
```

Results with valid command (PiDocs is the correct folder name):

```
 0
 Return code was equal to 0
```

Results if invalid command (used PDocs as incorrect folder name):

```
'/PDocs' aka '/home/pi/GDRIVE/PDocs' doesn't exist locally nor remotely 

8
Return code was not equal to 0

now reassigning output 
print output again

mailtext is next
```

After I print standard out, it won't print it again or assign to `mailtext` and print.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Lists and `shell=True` don't usually mix well; I'm not aware of *any* case when you would want to use it. Just pass the string as the first argument.

Comment: You're printing the same empty string in all *three* cases. `drive` doesn't appear to write anything to standard output when there is an error; it's not clear why you think there is (or should be) a difference between the two `print output` lines.

Comment: "'/PDocs' aka '/home/pi/GDRIVE/PDocs' doesn't exist locally nor remotely" is the standard output of the 'Drive" command called and is printed when with the first 'print output' before the 'If" statement which then fails(return code !=0). What I can't figure out is why I can't continue to work with the 'output' variable to print it again or reassign it.

Comment: when it is successful, as in the first example with the valid file name, there isn't any stdout.

Comment: That string is printed to standard *error*, not standard output.

Comment: -__-.  Thank you!   had just been staring at it too long.

Comment: What had me confused was the fact that it printed once so had been assuming I had accessed the right output.  I added stderr=PIPE to the Popen statement and changed the output = p.communicate()[0] to output = p.communicate()[1]